# Why I'm missing Bootstrap glyphicons in XPages?

Tags: css, xpages, glyphicons

I'm using the latest Extension Library 11 at time of this posting.  Some glyphicons are available while others are.  When inspecting the bootstrap.min.css file with Firebug, I noticed the glyphicons I can render on my page are visible in this file, while the icons I cannot get to display shows up as a empty box in the css file.

```
<pre>
.glyphicon-cloud:before {
    content: "☁";
}
.glyphicon-envelope:before {
    content: "✉";
}
.glyphicon-pencil:before {
    content: "✏";
}
.glyphicon-glass:before {
    content: "";
}
```

FYI: I do not have any loading errors on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this blog post contains the answer.
http://bootstrap4xpages.com/bs4xp/site.nsf/article.xsp?documentId=F435B6DC54486B67C1257B6B002E5A6C&action=openDocument

Comment: Thanks Dave and Oliver.  Turning off the setting worked.

Comment: Keep in mind that turning off aggregation might really hurt the performance of your application....

Answer (score 1):

I reported this earlier to GitHub. Follow the link for how to fix https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/issues/11

Answer (score 0):

You will run into the same problem when using a Bootstrap theme beside the one in Extlib / BS4XPages plugin. In that case I don't use the minified CSS and edit it, commenting out the part where the glyphicons generally are defined (references to the font resources). As the icons are the same in every theme you can get this won't do any harm and the icons keep working.
Some themes don't have the Glyphicon stuff in it and contain just additional CSS information for colors etc. In that case there is no problem with icons.